# Postfix (maildir and shadow file) to Zimbra 8.8.15 migration

Tags: zimbra

Hello guys as the title is saying Im trying to migrate from Postfix (users, passwords, mailbox) to Zimbra.
I see architecture changed over the years.
Do you know a script that does the job or how I can do it?

Comment: Postfix is just an MTA. On the other way, Zimbra is a complete collaboration solution which has MTA (Zimbra uses Postfix as its MTA), MDA, web interface (web-MUA), administration interface, directory and so on. So the question is not quite correct - please, clarify your current complete mail setup, not just "Postfix"

Comment: Yes you are right. System uses postfix and dovecot , 2 external relays and 3 mx. Users are the one on passwd and mailboxes have /maildir/<username> structure. I can dig into it more if needed. I would like to move those users to Zimbra but they are almost 200.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, currently users are authenticated with PAM from files and access mail via IMAP with Dovecot. This means passwords are likely encrypted irreversibly, thus users can not be simply moved to Zimbra while keeping their credentials. You can create all user's root ("INBOX") mailboxes programmatically [using Zimbra API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096136/zimbra-user-account-creation-using-soap-rest), but you can not set up same passwords as they were, if you don't know their passwords.

After creating mailboxes you may update MX from old system to Zimbra.

Now on how to move mail. I suggest `imapsync` utility to do that, but it requires you to be able to login both on old and on new system, i.e. you would need to know both passwords on the old and on the new systems. As admin, you can reset passwords to known values on old system, and temporary set known passwords on new system, then sync mail. You have to move mailboxes one-by-one, but this can be scripted, for example you can leave it running for a night. When mail is synced, you can invite users to change their password on the new system and use it.